# asp.net display data and send form from different viewmodels

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms, viewmodel

I have a webpage going where I want to display data of an image.
This data is structured as my ImageViewModel. In that same webpage, I also want to have a form to create a new tag. This is structured as my AddTagViewModel.
How would I be able to make use of 2 different viewmodels in one page?
This far, I've kept having trouble to actually use these 2 viewmodels in one page.
How would one properly do this?